# Mock location in windows 8 desktop application

Tags: .net, windows-8

I am using Geolocator to get device location in a windows 8 desktop application, is there a way I can test it by getting the os to simulate location changes by settings mock location ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this tool
https://github.com/juliankay/FakeGPS

> FakeGPS is a Windows driver which allows the user to provide geolocation information without a physical GPS device.

I tried it and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Same as you would for a phone app, you need to run your app in the visual studio simulator.

From there, you can change settings such as simulated location.

See the guide here https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh441475(v=vs.120).aspx#BKMK_Set_the_simulated_geo_location_of_the_device

Comment: thanks for your response, but I cant see the simulator dropdown in my solutions, isnt that because my app is not a store app ?